# php storing for loop values into an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm inside a while loop reading a csv, when I find an specific line, headers, I need to store that data into an array I could use later for next lines. My problem is the array only exists when I find the headers first time, but I don't know how to get it out of there. When I make `$arrlength2 = count($myArray)` is where I would like the array to exist.

```
  $headersFound = FALSE;
  $file = fopen('../csvfile.csv', 'r');
  while ($data = fgetcsv($file)) { 

    $myArray = array();  

    if (!$headersFound) {

      if ($data[0] == "Header") { 
        $headersFound = TRUE;
        $arrlength = count($data);

        for ($x = 1; $x < $arrlength; $x++) { 
          $var = $data[$x];
          $myArray[$x - 1] = $var;
        }

      } // end if $data[0] == "Header"

    } else { //if headersFound = TRUE

      $arrlength2 = count($myArray);

        for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength2; $x++) {
          echo $myArray[$x];
          echo "<br>";
        }

    }
  }
```

CSV is:

```
Título:,EVALUACIÓN DE ALUMNOS/AS POR MATERIAS,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Autor:,"Aplicación Séneca, CONSEJERÍA DE EDUCACIÓN, Junta de Andalucía",,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Fecha de creación:,13/11/15 - 13:11,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Alumno/a,EF,LCL,ING,MAT,MúS,REV,REL,FR2,OP1LC,LIBDI,LIBD2,BYG,GeH,VE,EPVA
"Ficticio1 Ficticio1, Ficticio1",7,6,1,7,3,,5,5,,6,1,5,4,,1
"Ficticio2 Ficticio2, Ficticio2",8,6,7,7,2,,,5,,6,7,5,8,5,7
```

My desired array I already have is `EF LCL ING MAT MúS REV REL FR2 OP1LC LIBDI LIBD2 BYG GeH VE EPVA`, I just would like it to exist where I'm reading next lines. I would need to pair each code with a number, so when I'm reading line `"Ficticio1 Ficticio1, Ficticio1",7,6,1,7,3,,5,5,,6,1,5,4,,1` , I could call $myArray[$x]

Comment: Can you post your `csv` & your desired `array output`?

Comment: Done, hope it clarifies a bit